# Creating equivalent to incf as macro-function in lisp

Tags: macros, lisp, common-lisp

I'm just starting to learn the concept of macro functions.

My teacher has asked us to create a macro function that would function exactly the same way as `incf`.

Here is an example he has given us for pop

```
(defmacro mypop (nom) 
   (list 'prog1 (list 'car nom) (list 'setq nom (list 'cdr nom))) )
```

Here is the regular function I'm trying to turn into a macro:

```
(defun iincf (elem &optional num )
   (cond
      ((not num) (setq elem (+ 1 elem)))
      (t (setq elem (+ num elem))) ) )
```

Here is my attempt at turning it into a macro :

```
(defmacro myincf (elem &optional num )
   (list 'cond
      ((list 'not num) (list 'setq elem (list '+ 1 elem)))
      (t (list 'setq elem (list '+ num elem))) ) )
```

However, I get this error and I don't know why:

```
*** - system::%expand-form: (list 'not num) should be a lambda expression
```

Also, I'm not sure whether my function would actually change the value of the variable at the top level.

So here are my 2 questions:

1. Why do I get this error?
2. Is the function I'm trying to turn into a macro fine? (if successfully turning it into a macro function, would it do what I intend to?)

PS: I know this exercise would probably infringe many common rules in lisp, but this is just for practice. Thanks! :)

Comment: I just want to tell you about [Portacle](https://github.com/Shinmera/portacle), a portable and multiplatform Common Lisp dev envirnoment (shipping Emacs, SBCL, Slime, Quicklips and Git), because it's the easiest way to get a nice dev environment and I know I did appreciate to find it :) and also about [lisp-lang.org](http://lisp-lang.org/), one *appealing* and modern website on CL, in case you didn't think that could exist (as I did) !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the error is that your syntax is invalid:

```
((list ...) ...)
(t (list ...))
```

The first element should be a function name or a lambda expression, so you would need to change it to something like

```
(list (list ...) ...)
(list t (list ...))
```

Although the macro isn't a very good one yet. First of all, the [backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) syntax would make the code much more readable. It allows you to write a template where only the specified forms are evaluated. For example, the given `MYPOP` macro would look like

```
(defmacro mypop (nom)
  `(prog1 (car ,nom)
     (setq ,nom (cdr ,nom))))
```

Only the forms with a comma before them are evaluated. Same with your macro:

```
(defmacro myincf (elem &optional num)
  `(cond
     ((not ,num) (setq ,elem (+ 1 ,elem)))
     (t (setq ,elem (+ ,num ,elem)))))
```

The `COND` shouldn't really be part of the expansion though. It should be evaluated during macroexpansion, and only the `SETQ` form from one of the branches returned.

```
(defmacro myincf (elem &optional num)
  (cond
    ((not num) `(setq ,elem (+ 1 ,elem)))
    (t `(setq ,elem (+ ,num ,elem)))))
```

The only difference between the two branches is that the first one defaults to `1` for `NUM`. A simpler way to achieve the same would be to give `NUM` a default value.

```
(defmacro myincf (elem &optional (num 1))
  `(setq ,elem (+ ,num ,elem)))
```

Of course, the standard `INCF` is a bit more complex, since it works for all sorts of places (not just variables) and ensures that the subforms of the place are evaluated only once. However, since the `MYPOP` example doesn't handle those, I don't think you have to either.

If you want to, a simple way to define such a macro would be

```
(define-modify-macro myincf (&optional (num 1)) +)
```

Or you could do the same manually with something like

```
(defmacro myincf (place &optional (num 1) &environment env)
  (multiple-value-bind (dummies vals store setter getter)
      (get-setf-expansion place env)
    `(let* (,@(mapcar #'list dummies vals)
            (,(first store) (+ ,getter ,num)))
       ,setter)))
```

But using `DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO` would be preferrable in a real program (shorter code, less bugs). You could read about [`GET-SETF-EXPANSION`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_get_se.htm#get-setf-expansion) and [`DEFINE-MODIFY-MACRO`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm) if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and useful answer. It took me a few days to study it and learn the corresponding syntax, but it was extremely helpful.